# React Native array background

Tags: arrays, react-native

I have two arrays of strings

```js
First = ["one","four","six","whatever"]
Second = ["one","mix","six","weather"]
```

The problem is:

I want to loop through these two arrays and if two strings at the same position in both arrays are the same, the color of the returned value should be green. If they are different the color should be red.

Like this:

- In the `First` array, the first string is `“one”` and in the `Second` array the first string is also `“one”`. As these two strings are the same the returned value needs to be green
- In the `First` array, the second string is `“four”`, and in the `Second` array, the second index is `“mix”`, as these strings are different, the result needs to be red.

So if two values from the same position are the same then it should be green otherwise it should be a red color.

I hope I explain what I need to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "green" and "red"?  Do you want the elements to be wrapped in `<Text>` with a style that changes the background color?

Comment: Yes that’s what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
check = () => {
        const First = ["one", "four", "six", "whatever"]
        const Second = ["one", "four", "six", "weather"]
        for (var i = 0; i < First.length; i++) {
            if (First[i] == Second[i]) {
                console.log('green')
            } else {
                console.log('red')
            }
        }
    }
```

Refer this;

Comment: Thank you very much for help.